# Obtener ultimo jefe mediante CTE en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, recursión, cte

Tengo un empleado de nivel idTipoEmpleado = 1 del cual solo conozco su idEmpleado que es 1, necesito el **idEmpleado** y **nomEmpleado** de su jefe de nivel **Jefe Final**

- Tabla **Empleado**

| idEmpleado | nomEmpleado | idTipoEmpleado | idBossParent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JUAN | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | PEDRO | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | CARLOS | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | ANTONIO | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | RAUL | 4 | null |

- Tabla **TipoEmpleado**

| idTipoEmpleado | nomTipoEmpleado |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | EMPLEADO NORMAL |
| 2 | JEFE INTERMEDIO |
| 3 | JEFE FINAL |
| 4 | DIRECTORES |

¿Como puedo hacer el select de tipo CTE para llegar hasta su jefe con nivel 3 omitiendo los jefes intermedios y posteriores a **JEFE FINAL**?

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser forzosamente usando CTE? Pregunto porque no es la mejor opción (tengo una serie de pruebas sobre este tipo de consultas).

Comment: Y qué has intentado? Llevas tres años en el sitio. Ya sabes que necesitaremos ver cómo va tu código hasta ahora. Además, tienes como diez preguntas y sólo dos respuestas aceptadas. Por favor, demuestra tu agradecimiento con los usuarios quienes te han respondido ya sea aceptando la respuesta o respondiendo los comentarios.

Comment: Pues es que a veces encuentro la solucion antes y se me olvida cerrar la pregunta o agradecer a los que amablemente respondieron

Comment: Ya que no has respondido, te dejo un artículo donde explico como hacerlo. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/introducing-the-set-based-loop

Answer (score 0):

**I. Creacion de tablas para la prueba**

```
create table Empleado (
     idEmpleado int not null
    ,nomEmpleado varchar(max)
    ,idTipoEmpleado int not null
    ,idBossParent int null
    ,constraint EmpleadoPK
     primary key (idEmpleado)
    ,constraint EmpleadoFK01
     foreign key (idBossParent)
     references Empleado(idEmpleado)
)
go


insert into Empleado(idEmpleado,nomEmpleado,idTipoEmpleado,idBossParent)
values
 (1,'JUAN'   ,1,2   )
,(2,'PEDRO'  ,2,3   )
,(3,'CARLOS' ,2,4   )
,(4,'ANTONIO',3,5   )
,(5,'RAUL'   ,4,null)
;
```

**II. La consulta**

La consulta CTE se define de manera recursiva tomando como base de la consulta la fila del empleado del cual se desean saber los jefes, realizando una unión recursiva con sus jefes y a su vez con cada uno de estos, es el que aparece comentado como `--Conjunto de miembros recursivos`

```
    ;WITH ConsultaRecursiva(idEmpleado,nomEmpleado,idTipoEmpleado,idBossParent,profundidad, IdSubordinado, NombreSubordinado)
    AS
    (
      -- Empleado
      SELECT idEmpleado,nomEmpleado,idTipoEmpleado,idBossParent as Jefe, 1 as escala, idEmpleado as IdSubordinado, nomEmpleado as NombreSubordinado
        FROM Empleado
       WHERE idEmpleado = 1 --Aquí el Id del Empleado del que se desea saber los jefes
      UNION all
      -- Conjunto de miembros recursivos
      SELECT jefe.idEmpleado, jefe.nomEmpleado, jefe.idTipoEmpleado, jefe.idBossParent, c.profundidad+1, c.IdSubordinado, c.NombreSubordinado
        FROM Empleado AS Jefe
             INNER JOIN ConsultaRecursiva as c
             on jefe.idEmpleado = c.idBossParent
          )
    --Consulta que obtiene los datos
    select 'El jefe de Tipo '+convert(varchar(30),cr.idTipoEmpleado)+' de '+cr.NombreSubordinado+' es '+cr.nomEmpleado
      from ConsultaRecursiva as cr
     where cr.idTipoEmpleado = 3 --Aquí el tipo de jefe que se desea consultar
       and cr.IdSubordinado<>cr.idEmpleado
     order by profundidad
```